# What is the correct implementation of Image.Save(Stream s, ImageFormat f)?

Tags: c#, image, xna

I have written the following code with the intention of converting a System.Drawing.Image into a Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D.

```
public Texture2D convertImage(Image img)
    {
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (img == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //make a new Texture2D
        Stream mystream = ToStream(img, ImageFormat.Png);
        Texture2D tex = Texture2D.FromStream(parent.GraphicsDevice, mystream);

        return tex;
    }

    private Stream ToStream(Image img, ImageFormat f)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(stream, f);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
```

Parent refers to the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game that is calling the function, the issue is that there are no compiling errors but when the code is run the program throws an ArgumentException "Parameter is not valid." on line 22. I can't work out what the problem is, I can only assume there is something wrong with the way I have used the code.

The image being passed to the function is a standard image and I am able to save it to a file using "*img.Save(filname);*", the error only arises when I attempt to save to a stream.

**Update**
It seems that the problem is that the System.Drawing.Image is being disposed of prior to my call to Image.Save(), this is resulting in all of the Image parameters returning "Argument exception occurred. Parameter is not valid.", so to elaborate on my original question, how do I stop an object from being disposed until I have finished using it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try msdn articels: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I already checked the MDSN page, as far as I am aware the code is sound, and yet there is still an exception.